# Move div to another div (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I writing ASP.NET app

I have one div, here is code:

```
<div class="title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;">
    <img class="click" src="@Url.Content(" ~/Images/plus_plus.png")" />
    <span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.question, new {@class="testclass", @readonly = "readonly" })
    </span>

    <a class="click2" style="margin-left:10px;">
        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/arrow.png")' />
    </a>
    <a style="margin-left:25px;" href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Questions", new {id = item.QuestionId})'>
        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")' />
    </a>
    <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Questions", new {id = item.QuestionId})'>
        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")' />
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to move it to another. Here is code:

```
 <div class="title2"></div>
```

As I understood, it need to be done via jquery.

I try to write this script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    $('.title').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
    $('click2').click(function () {
        var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
        elem.hide();
        $('title2').append(elem).show();
        elem.remove();
    });
</script>
```

But it not works. Where is my problem?

Comment: Is everything above `$('title2').append(elem).show();` working?  Or is it just that line?

Comment: nope , elem isn't hiding@BviLLe_Kid

Comment: You are missing the `.` in `$('click2')` and `$('title2')`, it has to be `$('.click2')`

Comment: Okay, so now block is hiding, but not showing in another div@CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: It could be this line is removing the title div from your DOM: elem.remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.hide` and append the `html` of your `elem` to the `title2`

```
var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
$('.title2').append($(elem).html()).show();
$('.title').remove()
```

I added some `<hr>` and remove some of you mvc code, to make the example working. It should not result in any problems for you.

```js
$('.title').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
$('.click2').click(function() {
  var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
  $('.title2').append($(elem).html()).show();
  $('.title').remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;">
  <img class="click" src="@Url.Content(" ~/Images/plus_plus.png ")"  />
  <span>
</span>

  <a class="click2" style="margin-left:10px;">
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/arrow.png")' />
  </a>

</div>
<hr>
<hr>
<div class="title2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank's so much. It helps

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, you forgot to include the `.` when trying to assign event listeners to specific elements with a specific class name.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $('.title').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
    $('click2').click(function () {
        var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
        elem.hide();
        $('title2').append(elem).show();
        elem.remove();
    });
</script>
```

Needs to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $('.title').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
    $('.click2').click(function () {
        var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
        elem.hide();
        $('.title2').append(elem).show();
        elem.remove();
    });
</script>
```

Also, I have changed the `.hide()` and `.show()` to `.detach()` and `.attach()`.

I have created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h6h3pca/).

It is not exactly what you have but simply just for visual.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="title">
    <p>
      This is a test
    </p>

    <button class="click2">
        Click Me
    </button>
</div>

<div class="title2">
    <p>
        This is test #2
    </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.title').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
$('.click2').click(function () {
    var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
    elem.detach();
    $('.title2').append(elem).attach();
    elem.detach();
});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank's it helps too.